# I need testing tips

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, testing, networking

I'm making a C# application in VS2010 that can act as both a client and a server (To communicate with other instances of itself).

My question is, what is a good way of testing the networking in such an application?

I can publish and run the application on another machine but I'd like to be able to debug both instances.

Comment: Omniscience's answer is really useful but I think I need to clarify, I'm wondering how to have the source be the same on both machines with visual studio installed on them and debug with that. I don't know if that's a good strategy though.

Comment: A more inventive way would be to have a threaded Server (assigning each new client to a new thread on the server). Then have a separate client program, that you can distribute. Example of a simple threaded TCP server: http://goo.gl/zm8g7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Testing Techniques**

Using Packet sniffers, such as [*Wireshark*](http://www.wireshark.org), to *monitor* and ***analysis packets***, such as their source and destination IP addresses, MAC addresses, port numbers, protocols, etc... For a *Nix environment there's [***TCPdump***](http://www.tcpdump.org).

[A basic guide to using Wireshark](http://portforward.com/networking/wireshark.htm)

I would also recommended reading ***Richard Blum C# Network Programming Book***. There's an Ebook copy available. Contains useful information about testing network communications...